# C# Linq First() raise exception "Sequence contains no elements" while LongCount() gives 1

Tags: c#, linq, exception, datatable

I have private `DataTable` variable `dt` that contain exactly 1 row.

```
// In debug session in the immediate window:
dt.Rows.Count
// shows 1 ;
dt.Rows[0]["uid"]
// shows "IDxxx"
```

Things look fine to me. While in the code, the next following line always give me the aboved mentioned exception. `Squence contains no elements`

```
var urow_ = usr_dt.AsEnumerable();
var urow = urow_.First<DataRow>(x => x["uid"] == uid);
```

In the debug session I can see urow_.Table.NextRowID = 2. 
This thing has a cursor ?

Before the First<>() call is executed, if I do the follwoing in immediate window

```
urow_.LongCount()
// I get 1.
```

I am new to C#. Any idea what this situation might be about?

EDIT:
Just in case any new comer to C# is as confused as I was.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx

```
Exceptions                | Exception   Condition
ArgumentNullException     | source is null.
InvalidOperationException | The source sequence is empty.
```

while the link kindly provided in comment below suggests

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
ArgumentNullException     | source or predicate is null.
InvalidOperationException | No element satisfies the condition in predicate.
                          |  -or-
                          | The source sequence is empty.
```

Comment: You are doing a `First()` with a condition vs a `LongCount()` without... The only element present probably `x => x["uid"] **!=** uid`

Comment: @xantatos, the documentation gave me the impression that this error is raised against a empty source not a empty result ? I though I would get sth like null...

Comment: Not really, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx): "InvalidOperationException: No element satisfies the condition in predicate. -or- The source sequence is empty."

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will give you a null, `First` will throw an exception if there are no elements.

Comment: First got source null exception ArgumentNullException, and empty origin exception InvalidOperationException. FirstOrDefault could be better option in your case

Comment: @Camlio Thanks, I am definitely looking at a different version. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx . OK, I will switch to `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: you did not mention anywhere what is "usr_dt"?

Comment: @Ben Note that this is the first time I've seen the `LongCount()` being used. Normally `Count()` is more than enough. Enumerables with more than 2 billion elements are fortunately very rare. And the version of `First()` you kinked was *without* the predicate, so it was really as you though... but a different overload :-)

Comment: @xanatos, Just graped it from the intellesense results, I don't really know it has a LongCount before that. :-D. Thanks for the explanation.